# Laravel 8 upload xml file to DB does not work

Tags: php, json, xml, laravel, payload

I have an issue with sending files with XML.
My Program works like this;
you upload a .csv file, which I parse in the React frontend to JSON.
My DB runs on Postgres where the Data will be uploaded exactly like it has to be.
But the thing is to send this same data, as an XML to the Oracle DB.
(For better understanding please check the code below)

I have tried many ways but it will only work when the data is set in the code.
Like here
WORKING EXAMPLE:

public function service( Request $request ) {

```
    $datas = $request->input('datas');
    
    $curl = curl_init();

    $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $dt = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $ho = $date->format('H:i:s');
    $endDate = $dt."T".$ho;
    
    for ($i=0; $i < count($datas) ; $i++) { 
        
        $v_0 = !isset($datas[$i][0])  ? "" :  $datas[$i][0] ;
        $v_1 = !isset($datas[$i][1])  ? "" :  $datas[$i][1] ;
        $v_2 = !isset($datas[$i][2])  ? "" :  $datas[$i][2] ;
        $v_3 = 9999;
        $v_4 = 1;
    
        $row_effects =  DB::table('target_groups')->insert([
            'STORE_KEY' => $v_0,
            'CUST_NO' => $v_1,
            'TARGET_GROUP_ID' => $v_2,
            'TARGET_GROUP_STORE_KEY' => $v_3,
            'ORIGIN_TYPE_CD' => $v_4,
            'created_at' => now()
        ]);
        $obj["status"] = $row_effects;

    

    // json to xml
    /*
    $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $dt = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $ho = $date->format('H:i:s');
    $endDate = $dt."T".$ho;
    */
    

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://oracleURL',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "bulk": [{
          "entity": "customer_data_update",
          "primaryKey": "r4f7546e-2545-40cd-a01d-471f2865d734",
          "action": "UPSERT",
          "sortorder": 1,
          "lastModified": "2021-10-04T09:33:10",
          "payload": {
            "STORE_KEY": "23",
            "SERVICE": "CustDataUpdate",
            "MODIFIER": "1910001910",
            "PAYLOAD_DATA": "<STORESET STORE_KEY=\"23\"> <DATASET NUM=\"1\"> <ROWSET TABLE_NAME=\"CUST_GROUP\"> <ROW NUM=\"1\"> <STORE_KEY>23</STORE_KEY> <CUST_NO>37252</CUST_NO> <TARGET_GROUP_STORE_KEY>9999</TARGET_GROUP_STORE_KEY> <ORIGIN_TYPE_CD>1</ORIGIN_TYPE_CD> <TARGET_GROUP_ID>444</TARGET_GROUP_ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> </DATASET> </STORESET>",
            "SOURCE_APPLICATION": "LOCAL_APP",
            "CORRELATION_ID": "r4f7546e-2545-40cd-a01d-471f2865d734"
          }
        }]
      }
    ',
    
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic code....', // ihave delete the base64 code here for showing porpose
        'Cookie: BIGipServerchange.......' // ihave delete the rest here for showing porpose
    ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    sleep(1);
    

    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return response()->json($obj);
}
```

The comment part shows what i also tried. Here the payload works fine so to see that the connection works.

NOT WORKING EXAMPLE:
public function service( Request $request ) {

```
    $datas = $request->input('datas');
    
    $curl = curl_init();

    $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $dt = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $ho = $date->format('H:i:s');
    $endDate = $dt."T".$ho;
    
    for ($i=0; $i < count($datas) ; $i++) { 
        
        $v_0 = !isset($datas[$i][0])  ? "" :  $datas[$i][0] ;
        $v_1 = !isset($datas[$i][1])  ? "" :  $datas[$i][1] ;
        $v_2 = !isset($datas[$i][2])  ? "" :  $datas[$i][2] ;
        $v_3 = 9999;
        $v_4 = 1;
    
        $row_effects =  DB::table('target_groups')->insert([
            'STORE_KEY' => $v_0,
            'CUST_NO' => $v_1,
            'TARGET_GROUP_ID' => $v_2,
            'TARGET_GROUP_STORE_KEY' => $v_3,
            'ORIGIN_TYPE_CD' => $v_4,
            'created_at' => now()
        ]);
        $obj["status"] = $row_effects;

    

    // json to xml
    /*
    $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $dt = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $ho = $date->format('H:i:s');
    $endDate = $dt."T".$ho;
    */
    

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://oracleURL',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "bulk": [{
          "entity": "customer_data_update",
          "primaryKey": "'.$uuid.'",
          "action": "UPSERT",
          "sortorder": 1,
          "lastModified": "'.$endDate.'",
          "payload": {
            "STORE_KEY": "'.$v_0.'",
            "SERVICE": "CustDataUpdate",
            "MODIFIER": "1910001910",
            "PAYLOAD_DATA": "<STORESET STORE_KEY=\"'.$v_0.'\"> <DATASET NUM=\"1\"> <ROWSET TABLE_NAME=\"CUST_GROUP\"> <ROW NUM=\"1\"> <STORE_KEY>'.$v_0.'</STORE_KEY> <CUST_NO>'.$v_1.'</CUST_NO> <TARGET_GROUP_STORE_KEY>'.$v_3.'</TARGET_GROUP_STORE_KEY> <ORIGIN_TYPE_CD>'.$v_4.'</ORIGIN_TYPE_CD> <TARGET_GROUP_ID>'.$v_2.'</TARGET_GROUP_ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> </DATASET> </STORESET>",
            "SOURCE_APPLICATION": "LOCAL_APP",
            "CORRELATION_ID": "'.$uuid.'"
          }
        }]
      }
    ', 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic code....', // ihave delete the base64 code here for showing porpose
        'Cookie: BIGipServerchange.......' // ihave delete the rest here for showing porpose
    ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    sleep(1);
    

    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return response()->json($obj);
}
```

I have tried where I type the Key and the date, still the same.
I have two .csv samples one with multiple data one with only one data.
Why does this not work, I need help.
Can you please help me?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: When i use the second NOT WORKING EXAMPLE, what needs to work. There is no error but the data is not in the ORACLE DB. I have make a few changes in the code before, like adding sleep(1) / without same issue. I have change for example <STORE_KEY>'.$v_0.'</STORE_KEY> to <STORE_KEY>"'.$v_0.'"</STORE_KEY>, still not work. It seems to be it does not replace the values exact in this fields. Or something else. I have another code before but i delete it and take this from postman.

Comment: Hello Nico, thanks for your response. First where I'm stuck the data i upload from a .csv file what is parse to JSON in the react frontend, is upload to the postgresSQL. In the same function (public function service( Request $request ) {) it need to be send also send to ORACLE DB like the BULK what shows the information and format. For my understanding the 'STORE_KEY' => $v_0, 'CUST_NO' => $v_1, 'TARGET_GROUP_ID' => $v_2, what goes to the Postgres goes not correctly to the Bulk.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: This is what i receive in the consol, when i check for ConstraintViolationException the answers are more to JAva related issue: = {\"code\":400,\"message\":\"An ConstraintViolationException with id f7a54ae5-dcff-45f9-aca5-8b18aed67365 occured. Refer to logfiles for more informations.\"}{\"status\":true}", "status": 200, "statusText": "OK",

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? The CURL function i was using i have replace with the one from Postman. To see where it maybe stuck i have change this like so; "bulk": [{
          
            "STORE_KEY": "'.$v_0.'",
            "SERVICE": "CustDataUpdate",
            "MODIFIER": "1910001910",
            "PAYLOAD_DATA": "<STORESET STORE_KEY=\"'.$v_0.'\"> <DATASET NUM=\"1\"> <ROWSET TABLE_NAME=\"CUST_GROUP\"> <ROW NUM=\"1\"> <STORE_KEY>'.$v_0.'</STORE_KEY> <CUST_NO>'.$v_1.'</CUST_NO> 
   like this way. To see maybe the format by Key and Date is wrong

Comment: ich hoffe das reicht

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - this makes it way easier to read the data

Comment: Ok i will try. Question why the Data does not go to Oracle DB?The  target.csv is upload to the Postgres DB, but in the same "for loop function" it does not upload to the Oracle DB. I have assume that like the example here the <STORE_KEY>'.$v_0.'</STORE_KEY> is not get from the code here correctly. By typing it in directly like this <STORE_KEY>23</STORE_KEY> it works. But this is not the point. For my understanding the values for $v_0, $v_1 does not go to the place not correctly. Maybe you ask Question what is not clear, so i can try to explain.